# Comprobar si un directorio es un repositorio git

Tags: php, git

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto con **git** y **PHP** a través de la librería [GIT.php](https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php), sin embargo no se que comando git usar, o de que manera puedo comprobar si un directorio es un repositorio.

He intentado usar `git rev-parse <path>` pero no he tenido éxito, también he tratado de comprobar si existe el directorio `.git` pero eso no necesariamente significa que sea un repositorio.

Lo que quiero lograr es comprobar si un directorio específico es un repositorio, por ejemplo:

`git [comando] <directorio>`

**¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo lograrlo?**

Comment: Ejecuta ls -la y si ves que existe una carpeta oculta llamada .git, estas usando git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo ejecutar `git status`. Si no es un repositorio (Incluso si creas el directorio `.git` de manera manual), tendrás el siguiente mensaje:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Si funciona, tendrás el siguiente mensaje:

> On branch `<rama>`.

Comment: Tambien he tratado de usarlo, pero para usarlo tengo que estar dentro del directorio, existe alguna forma de usarlo especificando el directorio que quiero comprobar?? por ejemplo: **git status /opt/repos**

Comment: @JuanPinzón ¿`Git::open('/path/to/repo');` no es suficiente para ello?

Comment: La función abre el repositorio si es un repositorio valido, sin embargo al recorrer los subdirectorios y hacer un open a un directorio que no es git lanza un Error fatal que no se puede capturar en PHP,

Comment: @JuanPinzón podrías colocar un `try-catch`, veo que en todo el árbol de llamadas lanza un `throw new Exception` con un mensaje. No tengo PHP a la mano para probar la librería pero creo que sí se puede manejar esa excepción.

Comment: Gracias ya lo solucione, tenias razon con el try catch, acabo de probarlo, estaba usandolo mal.